# jQuery scope with multiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tool that allows a user to create a dashboard and add widgets to it. Each widget is its own JS file that is loaded into the page.

To keep things the same across the board, I create a function called `load` which is triggered when the document is ready.

The problem is, each of the other modules that are included all have the same function called load which is causing problems.

While I can change the function name to something unique, I would like to see if its possible to keep them all the same where they are locked down to the scope of the file they are in?

```
/*
Module Details: Department Links - A collection of links specific to the users department or selected department
*/

$(function() {

  // Define our moduleID
  var moduleID = 1;

  // Load our module
  load(moduleID, '', false);

  // Create a event for dropdown change
  $('body').on('select2-selecting', '#Department_' + moduleID, function (e) {
    // When the user picks a department, reload this module and fetch those department links.
    load(moduleID, e.val, true);
  });

});

/*
  Load the module
  @moduleID: required.
  @departmentID: if not passed, the SP will use the viewers departmentID.
  @reload: passed when changing the dropdown so we only render the new data and not the whole module
*/
function load(moduleID, departmentID, reload){

    ... Do other stuff here
}
```

**I guess my question is.. With multiple functions called `load` in the various js files included, how can I trigger the one specific to its own file?**

Comment: Can you explain a little more? May be including the content of a sample file and the code snippet above interacting with the same

Comment: Two words: module loader. (Like Rollup, Browserify, RequireJS, Webpack, etc.)

Comment: @binariedMe - Each module (js include) is structured the same way. On ready it fires the load function which does something to the DOM. Imagine having 5 js includes all with the same function name called `load`. Typically this shouldn't be an issue as I think they are all within their own scope of the file but I don't believe mine is set up as such. It's calling load and triggering it in the other files that also contain that function instead of just its own.

Comment: See there is nothing like file scope at least in javascript. Code snippet imported from various files are concatenated and then execution occurs as per configuration of import. What you can do in this case is that you can wrap content of each file in a self-invoking function to isolate scope.

Comment: @binariedMe I tried wrapping the whole thing in the self-invoking function but something goes wrong. The `load` function interacts with the `DOM` so I think it is trying to make changes before its actually ready. Unless I am missing something..

Comment: unless you are trying to call load function outside any js file, self-invoking function should suffice.

Comment: can you give a fiddle?

Comment: @binariedMe It wont be a functioning fiddle but it has the code I am working with. - https://jsfiddle.net/ep6vurfL/

Comment: So self-invoking function did the job?

Comment: @binariedMe - Sadly no, I turned it into one but it fails to run. I think its trying to make a change to the dom in the load function before the dom has actually loaded?

Comment: I believe that is not the problem of load function's scope. its more of document loading thing.

Comment: @binariedMe -  Is there a way I could use a dynamic function name? The one unique thing about each file is the `moduleID.` Could I do anything like `loadModule_moduleID()` where moduleID is a variable? That way each file can have the same loadModule function but the ID is always different so there shouldn't be any conflict.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116498/discussion-between-binariedme-and-sbb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@binariedMe is correct..  There is nothing like file scope in JavaScript.. You can do like if you have any object which is separate in every file so you can write as follows...

```
`Object.load = function (){
      // do stuff
 }`
```

And you can call object.load for every module you are loading...!!

Comment: This may be something I could do - any chance you could tweak this fiddle to show its placement? https://jsfiddle.net/ep6vurfL/

Comment: Is department is unique object there... Cause if it is global then we can have like `department.load=function(){ //do stuff here}`

Comment: well my goal was to not have to specify anything specific to the actual module it self such as a naming convention like that. I basically want to create a "template" that I can just copy and use when needed. So regardless of what it was called, if they could all be the same in each JS include, it wouldnt matter to me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be because you would be declaring load function in each js file globally. I have created a plunker with the same setup and each load function is working isolated to other.
Please check the plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/uZJ8FFwJMfEvPsWAFWwE?p=preview

```
(function(){ //stuffs of each file
    // Don't put any global variable unless you want no scope isolation for the same.
 })();
```